# How to prevent android emulator from stealing focus of my full screen google chrome showing Jenkins with Wall Display Plugin

Tags: android, macos, android-emulator, fullscreen, jenkins-plugins

I know this is a very specific question but I'm running my Continuous Integration Server on a mac in the middle of the room (so everyone can see it) and every time the android tests run the simulator steal focus from Google Chrome showing the Jenkins Panel (with wall display plugin). I already used the headless version of Android Emulator but even with this the simulator steals the focus.

Similar question also postes here on mac exchange: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/39978/how-can-i-prevent-java-processes-from-stealing-focus/88435#88435

Comment: Any sense whether the problem is Jenkins or the emulator? IOW, if Jenkins runs some other command, do you lose focus? Or, if you run the emulator via a cron job, do you lose focus?

Comment: Any other command makes my fullscreen Chrome lose focus. When the (invisible) emulator is invoked he gain focus and after the tests run, Chrome recover focus.

Comment: If I am interpreting you correctly, then, this is a Jenkins issue, and so you might wish to consider changing the title of your question.